# nested select query with table name in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, nested

I am trying to select all distinct values from all tables that start with a specific name, like: 'logs_2020_12_01', 'logs_2021_01_02', ..To select all tables with this specific name is straight forward:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE 'logs_%';
```

The select I want for one individual table is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch FROM logs_2021_01_27;
```

but I cannot find a way to combine it to make the selection from all tables. I tried a couple of things but it does not work, like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch FROM (SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE 'logs_%')
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I'm confused by "all tables". Your first example selects only from a single table.  You might be after a UNION between your tables.  I don't know how you expect to select 'batch' from a result set that only selects a column called 'name'. Whats your table structures look like?

Comment: I have 2 tables named 'logs_2020_12_01' and 'logs_2021_01_02'; each table have a column name batch. What I want to do is to select all distinct batch from all tables. the result/output I need is the number of distinct batches per table

Answer (score 0):

What about using Dynamic SQL, stored your tables information into a temp table with id column and set it to identity.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ---identity column will be used to iterate
(
id INT IDENTITY,
TableName VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE 'logs_%';

-- choose your own results with where conditions

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(20)

WHILE @COUNT <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp) 
BEGIN

    select @table = TABLENAME FROM #temp WHERE id = @Count
    
    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT(batch) FROM '+ @table

    PRINT @SQL
SET @Count = @Count + 1

END
```

after your print result looks good, change it to EXEC(@SQL), thanks

Comment: SQLite does not support dynamic sql.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't realize it is SQLite problem

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support dynamic sql.
You have to select the column `batch` from each of all the tables and combine them with `UNION` so the duplicates are removed:

```
SELECT batch FROM logs_2020_12_01 UNION
SELECT batch FROM logs_2020_12_02 UNION
......................................
SELECT batch FROM logs_2020_12_30 UNION
SELECT batch FROM logs_2020_12_31
```

If you don't know the full names of the tables, you can get them with this statement:

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table' AND name LIKE 'logs/_%' ESCAPE '/'
```

and then use a programming language to construct a `SELECT` statement with `UNION` to get the results that you want.

Comment: yes, but I don't know the name of the tables, I know only that the name starts with 'logs_', this is why I was trying first to extract all table names with:
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE 'logs_%';

Comment: @Lucian you can't do this with SQLite. You could use a programming language to access the tables individually.